# Same fragment with different navgraph by hiltNavGraphViewModels

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

I followed single activity pattern for my app. My MainActivity has a bottom navigation with 4 fragments.

[image: main nav graph]

**nav_home** and **nav_video** have same fragment so I want to HomeViewModel and VideoViewModel keep their states within these graphs. As you can see below.

**nav_home.xml**

[image: nav home graph]

**nav_video.xml**

[image: nav video graph]

On my fragment I use *hiltNavGraphViewModels* extension to keep viewmodel states.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CourseDetailFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_course_detail),
    LoadingDelegate by LoadingDelegateImpl(), NavigationDelegate by NavigationDelegateImpl() {

    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentCourseDetailBinding::bind)
    private val viewModel: CourseDetailViewModel by viewModels()
    private val categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_video)
    private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_home)
```

If I reach this fragment from home, categoryViewModel throws exception and it says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID 2131362218
> is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is
> Destination(com.example.app:id/courseDetailFragment)
> label=CourseDetailFragment
> class=com.example.app.ui.course.CourseDetailFragment

[image: logcat exception]

On the other hand, if I reach this fragment from video, homeViewModel throws same exception.

Any help would be most welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use this:

```
private val sampleViewModel: SampleViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(findNavController().graph.id)
```

However in my case, the vm is lazy initialized even before `onCreate()` and `findNavController()` is not yet available at that time.

Here's what I did:

```
fun provideVM(): SampleVM =
hiltNavGraphViewModels<SampleVM>(findNavController().graph.id).value
```

`provideVM()` is called during `onViewCreated()`